# Verifying a subbasis of the weak topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

So, I am working on a problem and I have shown that for $0 < p < 1$, $(\ell^p)^*= \ell^\infty$, I am now asked to show that the set of all $x$ with $\sum |x(n)| < 1$ is weakly bounded, but not originally bounded. I pretty much have this accomplished based on the assumption that for fixed $y \in \ell^\infty$,
$$\Omega_y = \left\{x \in \ell^p : \left|\sum x(n)y(n)\right| < 1\right\}$$ We have $\{\Omega_y : y \in \ell^\infty\}$ a sub basis of the weak topology.

I think I need to show that any open set in $\ell^p$ with respect to the weak topology can be writen as the union of these sets. Where open sets have the form (I am not sure if this is the correct open set form.)
$$
O =\left\{ y(n) : \left( \sum |x(n)y(n)|^p \right)^{1/p} < c, y\in \ell^\infty \right\}
$$

and that finite intersection of these sets $\Omega_y$ are still open.

I am just confused in general on how to do this, any help is appreciated.